# Issue running code before and after multiprocess threads

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Hello all this code will run but the second print statement is not executing after the worker threads.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
     jobs = []

     print 'starting for loop'
     for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
     print 'after for loop'
```

I am getting this for output:

```
starting for loop
Worker: 1
after for loop
Worker: 0
Worker: 3
Worker: 4
Worker: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for i in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
 for p in jobs:
     p.join()  # wait for the process to finish
 print 'after for loop'
```

Or more simply:

```
 print 'starting pool'
 Pool().map(worker, range(5))
 print 'after pool'
```

Comment: tried it and got Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threadingTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    Pool().map(worker, range(5))
NameError: name 'Pool' is not defined

Comment: @KyleSponable `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool`

Comment: one last question how do I pass parameters to the workers with pool? That is really cool! Thanks man!

Comment: @KyleSponable the second argument to `map` must be a list of arguments, each worker gets one element of the list.